# How to extract words that follow "By" to extracting author names

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract possible author names from an article. I am working under the assumption that the author name is in a byline

```
"By FirstName LastName"
```

or

```
"By FirstName MiddleName LastName"
```

and the first, middle and last names all start with a capital letter.

How can I use a regex to extract all 2-3 word strings that follow "By", that also meet the above conditions?

For instance, if the article has the text

```
"By Barack Obama on January 20th 2017. By January 2017, we all know Obama will no longer be the president"
```

it would extract

```
"Barack Obama"
```

and

```
"January"
```

as possible author names, and I will then do the work of determining which is the right one.

Currently my regex is:

```
/By ([A-Z][\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)/
```

However, when I use this on the string

```
"By Alex Jackson Olerud"
```

it seems to return both

```
"Alex Jackson Olerud"
```

and

```
" Olerud"
```

I am using Ruby as my preferred language, but any language-agnostic solution would suffice.

Comment: This has a strong smell of being an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)". Giving us background on the problem, along with how you arrive at the string might allow us to suggest a better path. For instance, scraping text incorrectly can result in run-on text forcing us to have to try to match small chunks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

```
str = "By Barack Obama on January 20th 2017. By January 2017, we all know Obama will no longer be the president. 
By A. B. Cecil"

def find_authors(str)
    str.scan(/
    (?<name> # a named capture group for one of the names
            \p{Lu} # starts with an upper case letter, unicode so will work also for e.g. Åsa
            (?: \. | \p{Ll}+) # followed by a period or some lower case letters
    ){0} # zero matches, this is just a subroutine to be used again

    (?<=[Bb]y\s) # lookbehind to make sure the author is after a by or By
    (?<wholename> # capture group to extract the whole name
        \g<name> (\s \g<name>){1,2} # a name should have a least two components
    )/x).map(&:last) # remove the match by the <name> group from the result
end

def find_authors_oneline(str)
    str.scan(/(?<name>\p{Lu}(?:\.|\p{Ll}+)){0}(?<=[Bb]y\s)(?<wholename>\g<name>(\s\g<name>){1,2})/).map(&:last)
end

p find_authors str
>> ["Barack Obama", "A. B. Cecil"]
p find_authors_oneline str
>> ["Barack Obama", "A. B. Cecil"]
```

You can read about [regex subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) and the [regex /x modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the second capture group `(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)` is throwing you off. Try using a non-capture group like `(?:\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)`

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "By Barack Obama on January 20th 2017. By January 2017, we all know Obama will no longer be the president"

str.scan(/(?:By )((?:[A-Z][A-Za-z]+ ?+)+)/).flatten.map(&:strip)
#=> ["Barack Obama", "January"]
```